# Duhamel's formula for a critical operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, semigroup-of-operators

I have an operator that has a non-trivial solution to the homogeneous equation.

Let $\hat{e}_0$ be the critical eigenvector and C(t) be the corresponding amplitude of an operator $\frac{d}{dt} - \mathcal{L}$ such that $(\frac{d}{dt} - \mathcal{L}) C(t) \hat{e}_0 = 0$.

Otherwise, $\mathcal{L}$ has a discrete spectrum and complete orthonormalised basis of eigenvectors.

I know by the Fredholm alternative, that I cannot now solve this equation uniquely
\begin{equation}
(\frac{d }{d t} - \mathcal{L}) u = f
\end{equation} where $f$ is a forcing term. However, can I still write the solution in the following form?

\begin{equation}
u = e^{t\mathcal{L}} u_0 + \int^t_0 e^{\mathcal{L}(t-s)}f(s) ds 
\end{equation}

How do I specify the homogeneous solution in the above format?

Best wishes,

Catherine

Comment: What does '$C(t)$ be the corresponding amplitude of an operator $\mathcal{L}$' mean? The critical eigenvector can have an amplitude, but an operator doesn't. Also, Fredholm says that for the equation to have a solution, $f$ must be orthogonal to the homogeneous solution of the adjoint problem. Denote $\partial_{t}-\mathcal{L}:=M$ and let $v$ solve the adjoint problem $M^{*}v=0$. Then for some suitable inner product we have \begin{align} \langle M u, v \rangle &= \langle u, M^{*} v \rangle \\ &= \langle u, 0 \rangle \\ &= 0 \\ &= \langle f, v \rangle \end{align} up to evaluated integrals.

Comment: Yes, but in the case that $d/dt - \mathcal{L}$ has a non-trivial solution this equation is not unique.